# IOS App Development for double telepresence robot

Tags: ios-app-extension

I am developing an iOS app to control the double telepresence robot. How do I establish bluetooth connection from the app with the robot?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have not tried it on Double telepresence robot. I started with a simple UI Tutorial with buttons and text. Now I have trying to use the framework provided at https://github.com/doublerobotics/Basic-Control-SDK-iOS. I have not been able to use it though.